# How to estimate confidence intervals of an arbitrarily weighted least-squares fit parameters

Tags: regression, correlation, confidence-interval, estimation, least-squares

I would like to use this procedure for estimation of the confidence interval in Nonlinear Least Squares:

[How to estimate confidence interval of a least-squares fit parameters by means of numerical Jacobian](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238378/how-to-estimate-confidence-interval-of-a-least-squares-fit-parameters-by-means-o)

However my error is weighted:

$$ \epsilon_n  = (w_n(y_n-f(x_n))$$

Most of time I use a relative error, weighting by the inverse of the data during fitting, because my data cover several order of magnitude:

$$\epsilon_n  = (\frac{y_n-f(x_n)}{y_n})$$

How should I calculate the confidence intervals in both cases?

According to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389808/using-whites-robust-co-variance-matrix-vs-weighted-least-squares-to-correct-for?rq=1), which is valid for linear LS I would suggest for NLS that:

\begin{eqnarray*}
Var\left(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_{weighted}\right) &  = & \sigma^{2}\left(\boldsymbol{J}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{WJ}\right)^{-1}
\end{eqnarray*}

were J is the jacobian and $\sigma$ the variance

The 3th parameter  + CI would be: \begin{align}
\beta_{3 \ weighted} \pm 1.96\sqrt{Var\left(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_{weighted}
\right)_{33}}
\end{align}

**Is it true?**

Note: According to Chapter 11 of Applied Linear Statistical Models by Kutner, Nachtsheim, Neter, and Li, 5th ed. :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{\sigma}_r^2=\frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\epsilon_n)\right)^2
\end{eqnarray*}

Regards